# What is the correct http status code when URI parameter is wrong

Tags: http, rest

Given i have a HTTP-Interface, and for example

`POST /user`

expects some specific JSON to be posted (for example `{"username": "keppla"}`), or

`GET /search`

expects a parameter like `/search?term=whatisearch`

When the client does not send the expected data, what would be a correct error code?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error

Comment: i read this list, but none of them strikes me as obvious.

Comment: just send a 200 with a json error object, it is more customisable in most cases that way anyway

Comment: @davin  That would be a bad idea.

Comment: @davin that is a pragmatic alternative, but in my opinion is not very 'RESTy', because 200 would imply, that there is a resource, and it is the error object.

Comment: hmmm, i could have sworn i wrote 400, and its too late to edit...

Comment: @davin  There is nothing wrong with returning a 400 and including a Json error object to describe the error in more detail.  If fact the HTTP spec says you should do this.

Comment: @davin Then that would be a great idea :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

400-499 is range for incomplete client requests. Looks like 400 is the right error code for your use case.

400 - Bad Request, The server could not understand the request, probably due to a syntax error.

Comment: i felt, the 'probably due to syntax error' would be kind of misleading (the requests are syntactically correct).

Comment: There is also 417, Expectation failed, Value in the Expect request header could not be met

Comment: but there's no request expectaion. As i understand 417, it is to answer to requests with 'expect' headers. 400 seems to be more apropriate

Comment: hmm yeah right, 417 is about the server not able to meet the expectation http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.18
400 seems appropriate.

Comment: 400 seems appropriate. Syntax error as in your application is expecting /search?term=whatever but unexpectadly request ended with /search or requested contains unexpected /search?term=' inject sql'

Answer (score 4):

422 is a possibility, but it is not commonly used, as it is not widely known that it is permissible to use WEBDAV status codes even when you are not doing WEBDAV.

> 422 - The request was well-formed but
>   was unable to be followed due to
>   semantic errors

For the second scenario, you could argue that a 404 is more appropriate as it is the URI that is not correctly formed, rather than the request body.